# How do I get IntelliJ to keep console, db console, etc all visible?

Tags: intellij-idea

Whenever I run something, the bottom window always fully replaces the other windows. For example, if I first open the Database Tool Window and execute a select statement, it shows the rows in the bottom output. If I then run my java program, it closes that and replaces it with the app's output console. I want them side by side.

How do I tell it what to keep open at the bottom? (I tried pinning a tab but it still goes away)

Answer (score 1):

do you want this?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnT5h.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieW7L.png)

try click split mode in your first window (ex Database Tool Window)

Comment: I'm able to get that mode but it doesn't stay.

Comment: i checked show toolbar, pinned mode, docked mode in first window. is not working?

Comment: No, it doesn't retain that